# Loop list in jquery and use the looped values

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

In my last question I was having problems looping through a list with jQuery. Then we figured this out and it worked perfectly:

```
public List<Sale> AllSales { get; set; }

for (var i = 0; i < <%= AllSales.Count %>; i++) {

}
```

I now need to use the values inside the loop so I thought it would be as simple as this  :

```
   for (var i = 0; i < <%= AllSales.Count %>; i++) {
       var date = <%= AllSales[i].Date %>;
       alert(date);
   }
```

When I first tried this, it said "The name 'i' does not exist in the current context
", so I just put 0 instead of i instead of `AllSales[0]`. Then nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `javascript loop` which you want to `iterate on server side list` this is not possible. You can use `ajax` to send data to client side. This is a nice [article](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) for using jQuery ajax with csharp.

Assigning the values of your list separated with comma to some hidden field and accessing that hidden field in javascript could be a possible solution. But if you want to use more attributes of your list object then it would be very messy solution. Using `ajax` is best option.